# Как реализовать перетягивание элементов в ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

Есть ExpandableListView, в нем несколько элементов верхнего уровня, и в них десяток вложенных элементов списка!

Проблема состоит в том, что нужно реализовать возможность, перетаскивание вложенных элементов, как в области одной группы, так и в другие группы !

Возможно стандартного решения этой задачи нет ? Как поступить в данной ситуации ?

**Как можно это сделать ? Что нужно использовать ?**

Comment: Стандартного решения для такого drag'n'drop-a точно нет.  Попробуйте тут посмотреть https://github.com/sreekumarsh/android/tree/master/Drag%20N%20Drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько библиотек, позволяющих это сделать (перечислены явно не все):

1. [Drag and Drop Expandable ListView](http://Drag%20and%20Drop%20Expandable%20ListView), предложенная Андроид Андроидом в комментарии
2. [DragListView](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView). На демо нет `ExpandableListView`, но обратите внимание на `BoardView`, возможно, Вам понравится такая реализация.
3. [Advanced RecyclerView](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview), основанный на более кастомизируемом `RecyclerView` вместо `ExpandableListView`. [Здесь](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/demo_d_with_section) как раз пример использования drag-and-drop с группированым списком.

Если использование сторонних библиотек по какой-то причине невозможно, то [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635688/drag-and-drop-listview-without-library) можно найти пример самостоятельной реализации drag-and-drop, правда для обычного `ListView`

В общем случае, я бы советовал воспользоваться [Advanced RecyclerView](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) из-за развёрнутой документации и возможностей по кастомизации. Если Вам необходимо максимально простое решение, то, вероятно, [Drag and Drop Expandable ListView](http://Drag%20and%20Drop%20Expandable%20ListView) будет лучшим вариантом.